# Is there a way to add opportunity products in salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am looking at a way to add opportunity products on salesforce1. Is there a way to do it currently?

If not a direct way any workarounds ?

I could only find ideas
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l20zAAA

Answer (score 1):

We have written a couple of Apex triggers, based on new product drop downs in the opportunity itself, that allows a template of products, values and quantities to be auto added to the opportunity.

This collection of routines wasn't designed with the mobile app in mind, but it does solve this problem beautifully!!